# Binary search tree iterative preorder traversal without additional storage

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

For inorder binary search tree traversal there is an iterative algorithm that uses no auxiliary memory (stack, parent pointers, visited flags) known as [Morris Traversal](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/). Is there a similar algorithm for preorder and postorder traversals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just worked out a solution for preorder traversal, might work

```
Initialize current as root 
While current is not NULL
If current does not have right child
  a) print current root
  b) Go to the left, i.e., current = current->left
Else
  a) print current root
  a) Make the whole right sub-tree of current as the left node of the rightmost child in the left sub tree(inorder predecessor of current)
  b) Go to the left child, i.e., current = current->left
```

do comment if it there is something wrong with the algorithm